# How to securely deploy a Django project on client machine server without code visibility?

Tags: python, django, security, encryption

I have a Django project which my Clients want to run on their server but I do not want them to have access or be able to read my code.

I have looked at several blogs on internet but I could not find a solution to securely hide my code or encrypt them for non readability.

I have tried creating binaries and also encrypting my .py files but it did not work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: what does "have tried creating binaries and also encrypting my .py files but it did not work." mean?

Comment: Short answer: No. You can't. But you can make the folder hidden. But the code still works.

Answer (score 1):

no... you cannot protect your code once it is on a machine that they have access to.

you can make it (marginally) harder by converting all your pyfiles to pyc and putting it in a debian package or something(you can use tools like pyinstaller to help with this) ...

but if they are determined they can get it ... all that other stuff is more likely to make your life a pain in the ass, than to solve whatever problem you might think your solving

perhaps a good question is why do you care if they can see the source if they paid you for it? surely if they hired you to do it in the first place, they are not technical enough to solve most issues without assistance as well. even if its a pretty simple site

another option is to just tell them no and host it on your server anyway